# Java iText - special characters not being displayed

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm trying for quite some time now to generate a PDF in Java using itextpdf (com.itextpdf kernel,layout,form,pdfa) with text containing special characters (äöüß). I tried several things in different variations, like loading a TTF file and setting the encoding:

```
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont( "font/FreeSans.ttf") ;
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont( fontProgram, "UTF-8" ) ;
document.setFont( font );
```

This way it just doesn't display special characters at all.

This doesn't work either:

```
var font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA, PdfEncodings.UTF8);
document.setFont( font );
```

I haven't found any solution to this and the official tutorials don't seem to have a solution.

Other encodings just render placeholder characters.

this is how I add the text:

```
 PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(filename);
 PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
 Document document = new Document(pdf);
 Paragraph p = new Paragraph("äüöß");

 document.add(p);
 document.close();
```

edit: I just realized that it works when I load the text from elsewhere like an input field, instead of passing a normal string. How can I make this work with hardcoded strings?
I tried re-encoding the string as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-encode-utf-8
but none of these methods work either. It always shows wrong characters.

```
PdfFont freeUnicode = PdfFontFactory.createFont("font/FreeSans.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
 String rawString = "äöüß1234'";
  byte[] bytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(rawString);

        String utf8EncodedString = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(bytes);

        document.add(new Paragraph().setFont(freeUnicode)
                .add(utf8EncodedString));
```

edit: The encoding in the source code editor is UTF-8 and I passed UTF-8 to the createFont() method, but that didn't work. When I pass CP1252 and change the source code encoding to ISO-8859-1, it shows the correct characters. Really strange how I couldn't find much information about this problem.

Comment: As your issue only occurs for hardcoded text, i assume your  source code editor uses a different encoding than your compiler assumes in the source code.

Comment: The encoding in the source code editor is UTF-8 and I passed UTF-8 to the createFont() method, but that didn't work. When I pass CP1252 and change the source code encoding to ISO-8859-1, it shows the correct characters. Really strange how I couldn't find much information about this problem.

Comment: That means that you call your Java compiler so that it assumes a source code encoding of ISO-8859-1. Instead of changing the source code encoding, you also could have changed your compiler call to assume utf-8. You don't find much about this because the normal IDEs automatically use the appropriate encoding when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Android Studio (java files), both with data from hardcoded text and with data from users fields.

Changing

```
BaseFont fontName = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/verdana.otf","UTF-8",BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

to

```
BaseFont fontName = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/verdana.otf","ISO-8859-1",BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked for you when reading info from outside than the problem you are experiencing is most likely your environment encoding. I.e. your strings are not read as UTF-8 or any other encoding that supports your characters. So, I would suggest to convert your `String rawString = "äöüß1234'";` into Unicode sequence to check that your string indeed properly encoded.
You can try this code:

```
String testStr1 = "äöüß1234'";
String encoded1 = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(testStr1);
String restored = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(encoded1);
System.out.println(testStr1 + "\n" + encoded1 + "\n" + restored);
```

The result should be:

```
äöüß1234'
\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df\u0031\u0032\u0033\u0034\u0027
äöüß1234'
```

If it is not, you have incorrect default charset for your environment. But also as a workaround you can send the String  `\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df\u0031\u0032\u0033\u0034\u0027` instead of `äöüß1234'` and that should work. The class `StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder` is a good tool for testing thorny encoded issues, I used it very effectively many times. It comes with an Open Source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. Here is a [Javadoc for the StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder class](https://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html). The library can be obtained as a Maven artifact from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with source code and Javadoc)